# Guide for ios app development in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, applications

I heard that you can compile, build, release an ios app entirely in ipad. But I have been unable to find a guide for it on the internet. Can you please show me one, by giving me a link or writing down an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can download and use the Swift Playgrounds 4 app on an iPad running iPadOS 15.2 or later to build iPhone and iPad apps with SwiftUI right on your iPad.

You can refer to the following link to learn more and find relevant links in Apple Developer Portal further:

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=v868vy6e

To learn more about Swift Playgrounds, refer the Swift Playgrounds website on Apple Developer:

https://developer.apple.com/swift-playgrounds/

Swift Programming language, SwiftUI guides along with documentation on the relevant APIs can be found on Apple Developer website to learn more.